# `ALT-<return>` breaks ya-snippet

Tags: yasnippet

I have a short snippet template which I use to document my patient’s encounter in `org-mode`.
It consists of

```
 * Subjective 
$1
* Objective 
- Examination: $2 
- Investigations seem : $3

*  Assessment 
- $4
* Plan 
- Investigations suggested 
   - $5 
- Treatment 
   1. $6
```

But when I use <kbd>M-RET</kbd> (runs `org-meta-return`) within the snippet to create a new item, the snippet exits (the fields are no longer <kbd>TAB</kbd>able, the message `[yas] Snippet 0 exited.` appears in the `*Messages*` buffer). How can I prevent this? 
Kindly note I am not a programmer

Comment: What's the question? And please specify what you mean by *"the snippet breaks"*. Also, try `C-h k` in that context, followed by `Ctrl` + `Enter`, to see what key sequence Emacs is picking up and what command it is bound to.

Comment: @Drew by snippet breaks, I mean I cannot TAB further. The snippet ends

Comment: @Vaibhav I made some updates to your question to clarify it, but I had to make some assumptions (mainly, that you are using `org-mode`). Please rollback, or edit further if I wrote something incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is "not possible at this time", but you might have better luck with other snippet packages, e.g., [(autotype) Using Skeletons](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Using-Skeletons.html) or [(autotype) Tempo](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Tempo.html) (both of these are builtin to Emacs).